# Old hard drive seen as allocated space

Tags: hard-drive, gparted, fstab, fdisk

Old hard drive seen as allocated space

I have an old trusty 20.04 system and it's time to grow into a bigger machine.

The new machine is all set up with fresh 20.04 and bigger drives.

Everything looks good.

So I bought a SATA/USB dock, pulled out my old hard drive, put it in the dock, and connected to my new system.

I expected the new system to just "see" it and it does (as dev/sdd), but as all "unallocated space".

I didn't want to risk doing something to the drive/partition table so I pulled it out and put it back in my old system.

Works fine there. (PHEW!!!) Everything is ext4 and I've got about 6 terabytes of data to move.

Any suggestions? Copying across my home network is estimated at 165 hours.

Thanks,

Comment: usb docks can be problematic. try plugging the drive in with a sata cable

Comment: You have not said how big the hard drive is. If it is the 6 terabytes implied in the question are you sure the USB dock can support that size?

Comment: `PHEW!!!` does not matter here. Even if this is 6 TB of data, you have a backup if you care about the data at all.

Comment: Something similar happened to me a long time ago, and it turned out (in my case), the SATA/USB dock was broken.  Are you able to try the dock with another spare hard disk?  Or maybe borrow another dock from a friend?  (I'm hesitant to ask you to go out and buy a new one as I could be wrong.)